# In flutter, how to integrate facebook audience as mediation network with Admob?

Tags: facebook, flutter, admob, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

I am new to ad mediation. I have a flutter app and I have integrated admob using following admob_flutter plugin and its working fine on both Android and iOS.

> https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter

Now I want to add facebook audience as mediation network. I have followed the steps in following tutorial provided by google to setup audience account and integration in Admob portal.

> https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/facebook

My confusion is about facebook audience sdk to integrate. Which one should I add :

1. facebook_audience flutter plugin 
   -https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_audience_network.
2. implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:5.8.0.0' - google tutorial ask to add open source mediation adapter.
3. implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+' - facebook audience tutorial ask to integrate this sdk.

What is the difference betweek sdk and adapter? Should we have both facebook audience sdk and mediation adapter (Point 2 and 3)?
If only sdk is enough, then including flutter plugin is enough for both android and iOS?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add the `facebook_audience` dependency. If you simply add 
 `implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:5.8.0.0'` to your build.gradle it will automatically install the adapter in your app.
If you put point 2 & 3 both in your build.gradle it will integrate the adapter as well as the SDK. 
You require the SDK to show ads in your app, similar to your Admob SDK (`admob_flutter`) and the adapter is used to link it to your Admob Mediation.

Comment: They've come up with firebase_admob plugin for flutter. So you're saying that if I add that, then in build.gradle add the mediation:facebook:x.x.x. and the audience-network-sd:5" ... mediation should work? But ... how does it work ? Does the flutter plugin interact with the mediation:facebook library and so handles the mediation ?!  I'm confused as to which component communicates with which component...

Comment: I have my own question here, if you want you can answer there ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61579831/flutter-admob-ads-with-mediation

Comment: i need to integrate both point 2 and 3??? or it's work fine only with point 2?