# What are the changes needed to be done on flutter project to add Facebook Audience Network through Admob Mediation?

Tags: android, flutter, admob, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

I could not find enough information on the web on merging **`Facebook Audience Network`** through `Admob` `Mediation` in `flutter`. Can someone guide me in the changes needed to be done in the project after setting `Mediation` in `Admob`.

The changes that need to be clear are :

1. What are the `dependencies` I should add excluding `admob_flutter`?
2. What are the implementations that should be added to the `build.gradle`?
3. Are there anything to be done on any other folders?

It would be nice if there was an explanation for the `IOS` project too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In flutter, how to integrate facebook audience as mediation network with Admob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427424/in-flutter-how-to-integrate-facebook-audience-as-mediation-network-with-admob)

Comment: @Emile Almost, but not completely

Answer (score 3):

Facebook Audience Network SDK in the app-level `build.gradle` file.

```js
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

...
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.5.1.0'
}
...
```

Then, add a Network Security Configuration File

location :- `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    ...
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
    </domain-config>
    ...
</network-security-config>
```

Then in your application manifest `AndroidManifest.xml`, add the configuration to your application attribute as follows:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ... >
    ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, Can you be clear on network_security_config, is it mandatory

Comment: According to integration of facebook audience network with mediation guide explained by google developers is to modify your network security config file to support media caching.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully enabled it by just adding the `SDK` to the app-level build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.5.1.0'
}
```

After that i tested it using [mediation_test](https://pub.dev/packages/mediation_test) `package`.